# SQL - LEAD() Function

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause, window-functions

I attempting to use the following code:

```
 SELECT SkillTargetID, DateTime,
    lead(EventName,1) over (partition by EventName order by DateTime) as next_eventname,
    lead(ReasonCode,1) over (partition by ReasonCode order by DateTime) as next_ReasonCode
 FROM ucce1_awdb.dbo.Agent_State_Trace ast
 WHERE 
 EventName = 3 and
 ReasonCode= 0 and
 next_eventname = 0 and
 next_ReasonCode = 114
```

But I am unable to execute that query because of `next_eventname` and `next_ReasonCode`. Can someone advise me on how I should handle this?

Comment: `lead(EventName,1) over (partition by EventName` is useless, eventname will never change in the same PARTITION (currently it's quite similar to `where event_name = 0`). Same for next_reason_cde. Can you show some example data and expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You need a subquery:

```
SELECT SkillTargetID, DateTime, next_eventname, next_ReasonCode
FROM (SELECT ast.*
             lead(EventName) over (partition by EventName order by DateTime) as next_eventname,
             lead(ReasonCode) over (partition by ReasonCode order by DateTime) as next_ReasonCode
      FROM ucce1_awdb.dbo.Agent_State_Trace ast
     ) ast
WHERE EventName = 3 and
      ReasonCode= 0 and
      next_eventname = 0 and
      next_ReasonCode = 114
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use use a an alias defined in the `select` clause in the `where` clause... and you can't use window functions in the `where` clause. You need to move the filtering to an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SkillTargetID, 
        DateTime,
        lead(EventName,1) 
            over(partition by EventName order by DateTime) as next_eventname,
        lead(ReasonCode,1) 
            over(partition by ReasonCode order by DateTime) as next_ReasonCode
    FROM ucce1_awdb.dbo.Agent_State_Trace ast
) t
WHERE 
    EventName = 3 
    AND ReasonCode= 0
    AND next_eventname = 0 
    AND next_ReasonCode = 114
```

Note that I moved *all* the filters to the outer query (not only those that apply to window computations): that is because you (probably!) need the window functions to see the entire dataset, before applying the filters.